# Predicated needed for proof using structural induction

Tags: induction, propositional-calculus

I have a set, $F$, of boolean formulas defined inductively as follows:

$X_{i} \in F, \: \forall i \in \mathbb{N} \: \text{(variables)}\\
A \in F \implies \neg A \in F\\
A, B \in F \implies A \land B \in F\\
A, B \in F \implies A \lor B \in F$

I also have the mutually recursive functions $T$, $N: F \rightarrow F$ where:

$T(A \land B) = T(A) \land T(B)\\
T(A \lor B) = T(A) \lor T(B)\\
T(\neg A) = N(A)\\
T(X_{i}) = X_{i}\\
\:\\
N(A \land B) = N(A) \lor N(B)\\
N(A \lor B) = N(A) \land N(B)\\
N(\neg A) = T(A)\\
N(X_{i}) = \neg X_{i}$

I need to show, using structural induction on the definition of $F$, that $\forall A \in F$:

$T(A) \iff A$ "and has negation only on variables"

The suggestion is to define a stronger predicate that also makes a statement about $N$.  I cannot seem to come up with a suitable predicate and I am not entirely sure what the qualification "and has negation only on variables" means.  Structural induction itself is not a problem.

Any advice is appreciated.

EDIT:

Later, I realized that the qualification "has negation only on variables" must mean "has negation only on **arguments** to $T$ and $N$" and not the "variables" $X_{i}$.

Comment: Some hints: The function T corresponds to using De Morgan's laws, and the function N corresponds to negating the expression. Also, "has negation only on variables" means that a negation sign $\neg$ only appears in front of variables, and never in front of larger expressions. As an example, $\neg$ only appears in front of variables in $\neg X_1 \vee \neg X_2$ but not in $\neg (X_1 \wedge X_2)$.

Comment: It seems that T is _not_ applying De Morgan's Laws, rather that N is.

Comment: (Note: I don't have an answer, I just think this is an interesting question, so I'm trying to help) If we look at $\varphi = \neg(X_1 \wedge X_2)$, then $T(\varphi) = \neg X_1 \vee \neg X_2$, which is De Morgan's law, and $N(\varphi) = X_1 \wedge X_2$, which is just the negation of $\varphi$. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, not at all. My apologies. I missed the trick of defining $\varphi$ as a negation.

Comment: Hopefully you realize that $$T(A \land B) = T(A) \land T(B)$$ is meant to be interpreted as a notation about building an AST, not as actually evaluating boolean expressions.

Comment: I _think_ so. Strictly speaking, ASTs are outside the scope of this course. So, more narrowly, the utility of $T$ and $N$ seems to be that they map $F \rightarrow F$, allowing transformations of expressions through logical equivalence. Am I missing some other implication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T$ is a *transformation* with the property that :

> for all *boolean formula* $A \in \mathcal F$, $T(A) \leftrightarrow A$ and $T(A)$ has all the negation signs "pushed inside", i.e. in front of boolean variables $X_i$.

*Basis of induction* : $A = X_i$

$T(A)=T(X_i)=X_i$, by definition of $T$. Thus, $T(A)$ has all negation signs (there are none) in front of variables and $T(A)=X_i \leftrightarrow X_i=A$.

*Induction step* : the induction is on the number of *connectives* of $A$.

*($1$)* $A = \lnot B$; thus : $T(A)=T(\lnot B)=N(B)$.

Now we have to consider four sub-cases :

*($1_{atomic}$)* : $B = X_i$.

$T(A)=N(B)=N(X_i)=\lnot X_i$ and so : $T(A)=\lnot X_i$ has all the negation signs in front of variables.

But $T(A) = \lnot X_i \leftrightarrow \lnot B=A$ and we are done.

*($1_{\lnot}$)* : $B = \lnot C$.

$T(A)=N(B)=N(\lnot C)=T(C)$; $C$ has two connectives less than $A$ and thus the *induction hypotheses* apply, i.e. $T(C) \leftrightarrow C$ and $T(C)$ has all the negation signs "pushed inside".

Now, $A=\lnot B=\lnot \lnot C \leftrightarrow C$  and : $T(A)=T(C)$ and so : $T(A) \leftrightarrow C \leftrightarrow A$ and $T(A)$ (i.e. $T(C)$) has all negation signs in front of variables.

*($1_{\land}$)* : $B = C \land D$.

$T(A)=N(B)=N(C \land D)=N(C) \lor N(D)$ and $N(C)=T(\lnot C)$ and $N(D)=T(\lnot D)$. But $C$ and $D$ has two *conncetives* less than $A$ and thus the *induction hypotheses* apply to both $\lnot C$ and $\lnot D$, i.e. $T(\lnot C) \leftrightarrow \lnot C$ and $T(\lnot C)$ has all the negation signs "pushed inside", and the same for $T(\lnot D)$.

Thus $T(A)=N(B)=T(\lnot C) \lor T(\lnot D) \leftrightarrow \lnot C \lor \lnot D$ and $T(A)$ has all negation signs in front of variables, because so are $T(\lnot C)$ and $T(\lnot D)$ and the $\lor$ connective does not introduce any new negation sign.

But $T(A)=T(\lnot C) \lor T(\lnot D) \leftrightarrow \lnot C \lor \lnot D \leftrightarrow  \lnot(C \land D) \leftrightarrow \lnot B=A$, and it's done.

*($1_{\lor}$)* : $B = C \lor D$.

*Similar to* *($1_{\land}$)*.

In the same way we can manage the other cases needed to complete the *induction step* :

*($2$)* $A = C \land D$.

*($3$)* $A = C \lor D$.